# Only one record is Shown in Datagridview Loading from excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I need your help. I have two excel files and I want to show them into datagridview. I found a problem that datagridview just shows one of my data not all. I want to show data like these :

These are my data from [Sheet1$]

```
WSID          Lokasi      Saldo
1234          A           200
5678          B           300
```

And these are my data from [Data$]

```
WSID       Tipe Mesin   Lokasi      
1234         MF           A          
5678         MF           B          
9876         CRM          C
```

If I press radiobutton MF, data which will be shown is data that has Tipe Mesin value of MF. Actually it should be shown 1234 and 5678 but it just show 5678. Can anyone help me ?

```
private void TampilDataSaldo()
        {
            RadioButton[] radiobtn = new RadioButton[] { MFRB, CRMRB };



         string dir = LokasiSaldo.Text;
            konek.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dir + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";



koneksi.ConnectionString = string koneksi = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Dokumen\Alfon\Kerja\BCA\Program\Program-Pengisian-Uang-ATM-BCA-SOY\Program-Pengisian-Uang-ATM-BCA-SOY\bin\x86\Debug\ATM SLA SURABAYA.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES';";

        int saldo;
        Int32.TryParse(SaldoTB.Text, out saldo);
        int thresholdcas;
        Int32.TryParse(SaldoTB.Text, out thresholdcas); //baca angka yang diinput di NominalBox dan ubah jadi integer

        OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
        OleDbCommand command = kon.CreateCommand();
        OleDbCommand command1 = kon.CreateCommand();

        if(radiobtn[0].Checked)
        {
            kon.Open();
            command.CommandText = "select * from [Data$] where [Tipe Mesin] = '" + radiobtn[0].Text + "'";
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                konek.Open();
                System.Data.DataTable aksesdatatabel;
                aksesdatatabel = konek.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                konek.Close();

                OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand
                (
                    "select WSID, Lokasi, Saldo from [Sheet1$] where WSID = '" + reader["WSID"].ToString() + "'", konek
                );

                DataSet coba = new DataSet();
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command2);
                adapter.Fill(coba);

                var table = coba.Tables[0];
                var view = new DataView(table);

                view.RowFilter = string.Format("Saldo < '{0}'", thresholdcas);
                ViewDataSaldoGV.DataSource = view;

            }
            kon.Close();
            }
}
```

Comment: dude, you make a new table/ View for every row. read inside loop and store view outside while loop. can you handle it?

Comment: Debug your code and you will see why you have only one *data*. You are reseting the DataSource in the loop.

Comment: Ahh ! Thank you so much. I did it and it works ! Thanks in advance :) @lordkain

Comment: good to hear you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have stated in the comments. You are looping through each item and rather than adding the data to a collection outside of the loop you are creating a new object each time.

You will want to move the dataset outside of the while loop, and simply add rows to it inside of the loop. This way you have a single collection that is added to, Rather then creating and not using multiple 1 record datasets

Comment: Ahh thank you so much. I did it and it works ! Thanks in advance :)